# Kafka topic messages are gone after cluster restart

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, openshift

We have a two node Kafka tcluster running in Openshift. We created a topic with retention policy set to 30 days. This work as expected including individual broker restarts. However when Kafka cluster is restarted by scaling down Kafka statefulset are to 0 replicas and scaling it back up to 2 replicas all topic messages are gone.

Before cluster restart:

/usr/bin/kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell  --broker-list localhost:29092 --topic platforms.openshift.events --time -1 --offsets 1

platforms.openshift.events:0:73387

After cluster restart:

$/usr/bin/kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell  --broker-list localhost:29092 --topic platforms.openshift.events --time -1 --offsets 1

platforms.openshift.events:0:0

Is it expected behavior? We use mounted volume for Kafka topic storage.

Comment: What is the replication factor for the topic? If the topic data dir is volume mounted properly, then it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Replication factor is 2. Persistent volume is mounted at /var/lib/kafka and Kafka server runs with logs.dir=/var/lib/kakfa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I noticed is that kafka.properties set log.dirs=/var/lib/kafka/data not /var/lib/kafka. After changing volume mount point from /var/lib/kafka to /var/lib/kafka/data the problem went away.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question ! That solved my problem (had to suppress the 'lost+found' folder in /var/lib/kafka/data, but it finally worked)